# How to stream and play shoutcast radio server in j2me MIDP(java)?

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0

i have tried String url = "38.101.195.5:9156"
facing java.io.IOException: 11-Error in HTTP operation

code here

connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

dataIn = connection.openDataInputStream();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device have support to the JSR 234 - Advanced Multimedia Supplements, then you can use your API: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=234

The package "`javax.microedition.amms.control.tuner`" Description

This package contains Controls for various tuner settings. These Controls, if they are supported, can typically be fetched from a radio Player (for example a Player created by Manager.createPlayer(`"capture://radio");`).

See more in

```
public interface TunerControl
```

Comment: Hii,Thanks for Reply,I am new to Mobile apps,I am using Nokia Symbian Belle SDK 1.0 and Nokia SDK 1.1,can we Stream And Play ShoutCast Internet Live Streaming url 38.101.195.5:9156 on those Devices,Any Sample Code From your Side.and also if i Pass the url 38.101.195.5:9156 to Manager.createPlayer("38.101.195.5:9156"),i am facing Invalid URL,What Should i pass to createPlayer method

Comment: See other discussion about this problem or relation to your need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084766/mp3-streaming-using-player-switching